# Differential forms and vector analysis

Tags: vector-analysis, differential-forms

where can I learn about differential forms,  what they represent and how to integrate them.

PS: Where can I read about vectorial spaces and vectorial analysis,  especially how to integrate.

I need these to understand my physics course,  classical mechanics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of books about differential forms and each of us will have a personal favourite. If you are starting out, I would suggest maybe having a look at:

- [Vector Analysis Versus Vector Calculus](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Vector-Analysis-Versus-Calculus-Universitext/dp/1461421993/) by Antonio Galbis
- [Differential Forms:A Complement to Vector Calculus](http://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Books/Differential-Forms-Integration-Manifolds-Stokess-Complement-Calculus/0127425101/) by Steven H. Weintraub
- [Advanced Calculus: A Differential Forms Approach](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/cka/Advanced-Calculus-Differential-Approach-Modern-Birkh%C3%A4user-Classics/0817684115/) by Harold M. Edwards

Hopefully one of those will have what you need. I am sure there are also plenty of notes you could find online that cover similar material.

Comment: What do you like about the Weintraub book?

Comment: I think for someone just starting differential forms, it is a gentle guide into the field without being overloaded with new notation. There's plenty of points that irked me about the book though and it is not where I learnt differential forms (though I can safely say, with the fortune of hindsight, that I wouldn't suggest the book I used as suitable for a first foray into the field!)

Answer (score 0):

Try "Mathematical Physics" by Mary L. Boas. It is a very good textbook for learning things from the essential basics.